# Import GeoJSON into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geojson, import, mongodb

I want to import GeoJSON avaliable in the following dump into PostGIS but I am not able to import it. I already imported geousa data available in this public dump into MongoDB smoothly. Let me know is there a way to import this data directly or through MongoDB?

As this data is huge please check following data:

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [19.056792, 47.490894]}, "type": "Feature",
"id": "SG_1iYphlxn9BSHyGrpv1aXKc_47.490894_19.056792@1308163237",
"properties": {"website": "http://mito.hu", "city": "Budapest",
"name": "Mito Europe", "tags": ["online", "communication", "design",
"branding", "development", "mito"], "country": "HU", "classifiers":
[{"category": "Professional", "type": "Services", "subcategory": "Advertising"}], "href": 
"http://api.simplegeo.com/1.0/features/SG_1iYphlxn9BSHyGrpv1aXKc_47.490894_19.056792@1308163237.json",
"address": "N\u00e1dor u. 23.", "owner": "simplegeo", "postcode": "1051"}}
```

http://s3.amazonaws.com/simplegeo-public/places_dump_20110628.zip

Comment: You should warn that your dataset is 2.2 GB. For making it more attractive to help you, could you prepare test data with just couple of features? That is well enough for testing.

Comment: added data format for reference.

Comment: How have you tried to import the data, and what is the error message?

Comment: GDAL reads that one feature fine. You can test it yourself by saving it on the disk and running `ogrinfo -al sample.json`. You should really tell what you did and how did it fail.

Comment: I executed:

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=my_database user=postgres" "source.geojson" but I am getting error as:

FAILURE Unable to open datasource `source.geojson' with the following drivers. (showing list of drivers)

Answer (score 34):

You can use PostGIS's [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) to bring in just the geometry part of the GeoJSON.

Better yet, you can use [`ogr2ogr` to import the entire JSON document](http://morphocode.com/using-ogr2ogr-convert-data-formats-geojson-postgis-esri-geodatabase-shapefiles/):

`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=my_database user=postgres" "source_data.json" -nln destination_table -append`

(I haven't tested this with your data, add a comment if you have issues.)

Comment: I am getting error as :

FAILURE
Unable to open datasource `source.geojson' with the following drivers. (showing list of drivers).

Comment: That has to be the full path to your geojson

Comment: I added full path as well, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: You need the GeoJSON GDAL driver: http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html

Comment: gdal-bin is already installed in my system (ubuntu).

Comment: Finally I am able to execute this command but it stores only one record in table. But I can't see any error message while executing this command. What would be the reason for such unexpected execution?

Comment: I'm not going to download 2GB to look, but are your features a [`feature collection`](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#examples)?

Answer (score 5):

```
./ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=theDatabaseName user=postgres" "/Users/dev/Downloads/theGeometry.json" -where "name not like 'Whatever%'" -nln theFeatureName -overwrite
```

`ogr2ogr` displays a list of drivers when the file is not found. in that case just pass in the full path to the json file