# Enable users to read data from postgis-database using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have uploaded a geojson file to a fresh Postgis installation with ogr2ogr following this example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172092/import-geojson-into-postgis).

I than created a new psql user for my colleague without any special rights but afterwards I granted him access rights to the db and all rights to all tables in `public` following the first answer in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/granting-access-to-all-tables-for-a-user).

If I connect to the db in QGIS with the postgis connector and his credentials, I can see the table, however there is an error message telling me that I have to specify the `data-type` and the `SRID`. If I do so (data-type is multipolygon and SRID is 4326) I can import the table, however no single feature is shown.

If I connect to the db with my own user credentials that have all rights (`SUPERUSER`) I can import the table without any error, not even having to specify datatype and SRID. So the data is definitely okay.

I guess the problem is that granting all rights to all tables in `public` is not enough and somehow I also need to grant the rights to use the postgis extension which is in schema `postgis` or something like that. Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, The following edits to `schema` in `postgis` resolved the issue:

```
-- Schema: postgis

-- DROP SCHEMA postgis;

CREATE SCHEMA postgis
  AUTHORIZATION postgres;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA postgis TO public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA postgis TO pg_signal_backend;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA postgis FROM postgres;
```

Comment: This is ***not*** an appropriate way to manage a database. Best practice calls for "least privilege". Granting `ALL` to `public` is an *antipattern*.

Comment: how about posting an adequate answer then?

Comment: There are too many unquantified actions in the question to write an  answer. The best solution would be to start over, then create a login role and schema for the data owner (no data should ever be loaded as `postgres`),  load the data as that user, then create a role for read access, grant that role SELECT on the loaded table, then create a login role for the second user, and grant them the access role.